# Update a text column that contains a newline character '\n'

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, psql

I'm encountering weird behaviour of PostgreSQL where I try to run the following query

```
update posts 
set content = replace(content, '\n', '<br>') 
where content is not null;
```

and it's not doing anything to the data in the database. I **tried committing manually (including trying to run this query from psql) ** as well as setting DBeaver/pgAdmin to AUTOCOMMIT but to no avail.

The result tells me **37 rows have been updated, but the changes are not there**. If I try to commit it tells me 0 rows affected.

I have no triggers at all, so that's out of the question.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `e` before the literal:

```
update posts 
set content = replace(content, e'\n', '<br>') 
where content is not null
-- or better
-- where content like e'%\n%'
```

From the documentation ([String Constants with C-Style Escapes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS)):

> An escape string constant is specified by writing the letter E (upper or lower case) just before the opening single quote.